# Como hacer una preload mientras carga algo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Cuando carga la pagina, hay cosas que se demoran en aparecer; asique mientras carga aparezca un preload, no es necesario que me escriban el código de un preload, solo pongan //Preload aqui.
Pliz por ejemplo este sector con php.

```
<section id="post">
        <article class="post">
            <div class="up">
            <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `prueba` WHERE id_usuarios=".$AMIGO_USUARIO_RED;
                    $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    if(!$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                        echo "La consulta falló ";
                        echo "Error: Lo sentimos, error a al conectarse, reinicie la pagina.";
                        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
                        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
                        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
                        exit;
                    }

                    // No hay datos en esa consulta
                    if ($resultado2->num_rows === 0) {
                        echo "No Tienes amigos agregadoss";
                    }

                     while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {

                         ?>
                <a href="?page=profile&id=<?php echo $row2['id_usuarios'];?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row2['RED_imagen_perfil'];?>" alt="user">
                    <h3><?php echo $row2['RED_nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row2['RED_apellido']; ?></h3>
                </a>

                <?php
                     }
                ?>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="center">
        <?php

        if($row['POST_imagen'] == ""){
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
        }else{
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
            ?>

            <div class="imagen"><img src="<?php echo $row['POST_imagen'];?>" alt=""></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
            </div>
            <div class="downcent">
               <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"> Like</i>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
                <img class="comentuser" src="images/example/myuser.jpg" alt=""><span class="info">Usuario</span>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Comenta esta publicación">

                <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                <i>:v</i>
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
        </article>

    </section>
```

Comment: Usas jquery o estarias dispuesto a usarlo?

Comment: no quiero usar ningun frameworks, quiero aprender, estoy dispuesto a prenderlo aunque sea difícil.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo ni idea de PHP pero se que este tipo de problemas se solucinan con Threads. Espero que sepas ingles porque encontre un manual de como usar threads en PHP

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="post">
<article class="post_view_public">
          <div class="post_view_loading">
             <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
          </div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               function ocultar(){
                document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.add = "mostrar_loading_post" ;
                document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.add = "ocultar_objetos";
                }
            </script>

            <div id="post_view_public">
            <div class="up">
            <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `a_redcdark_social` WHERE id_usuarios=".$AMIGO_USUARIO_RED;
                    $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    if(!$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                        echo "La consulta falló ";
                        echo "Error: Lo sentimos, error a al conectarse, reinicie la pagina.";
                        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
                        echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
                        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
                        exit;
                    }

                    // No hay datos en esa consulta
                    if ($resultado2->num_rows === 0) {
                        echo "No Tienes amigos agregadoss";
                    }

                     while($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {

                         ?>
                <a href="?page=profile&id=<?php echo $row2['id_usuarios'];?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row2['RED_imagen_perfil'];?>" alt="user">
                    <h3><?php echo $row2['RED_nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row2['RED_apellido']; ?></h3>
                </a>

                <?php
                     }
                ?>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="center">
        <?php

        if($row['POST_imagen'] == ""){
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
        }else{
            echo $row['POST_texto'];
            ?>

            <div class="imagen"><img src="<?php echo $row['POST_imagen'];?>" alt=""></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
            </div>
            <div class="downcent">
               <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"> Like</i>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
                <img class="comentuser" src="images/example/myuser.jpg" alt=""><span class="info">Usuario</span>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Comenta esta publicación">

                <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                <i>:v</i>
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               function mostrar(){
                    document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.remove = "mostrar_loading_post" ;
                   document.getElementById('post_view_loading').classList.add = "ocultar_objetos" ;
                   document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.remove = "ocultar_objetos";
                    document.getElementById('post_view_public').classList.add = "mostrar_objetos";


                }
            </script>
        </article>

</section>
```

Este código se me ocurrió, se que no es para comentar el mio pero, es para que ya no respondan.

Pero si hay otra forma mejor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un simple div que muestre una imagen mientras está cargando, bien sea un espere un momento etc...

```
<div id="pg_cargando"><img src="tu imagen aqui" alt="" width="550" height="400" border="0" /></div>
```

Con el siguiente css:

```
#pg_cargando{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:999999;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Luego en el header inicias una función en JS que esconda la imagen de cargando:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function QuitarCargando(){
    document.getElementById("pg_cargando").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
 </script>
```

Y en tu body para que cuando acabe de cargar con el onload esconda la imagen de cargando y muestre la página:

```
<body onload="QuitarCargando();">
```